# How to find out which input type submit button has been clicked? Or how to get the value or name of the clicled button?

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have a form equipped with several buttons. The form has a textfield which basically shows the contents of the files uploaded by the user. Now clicking on any of these buttons submits the form, but I need to tag the content submitted with a keyword depending on which button was clicked and I need to do this in Python as afterwards these contents are being sent via a queue. And this is all done in Flask. Now my question is: Is there any way to find out which submit button was clicked in python?

Comment: use different `name=` for different buttons and later check which name you get in Flask. Or probably you can use the same name but different `value=` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your button a name, the clicked one will be sent through as any other input, so you can access it in Flask.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Create">
```

Or maybe use the same name with different values.

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Create">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It gives the element which you clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  var target;
  return target = $(event.target);
});
```